# Svg inside another svg can't change height with css

Tags: css, svg

## Example

In this example I've posted, I have two svg elements, each with a nested element with its own viewbox.

```css
svg {
  background-color: orange;
}

#inline {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#in-css {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 300" width=100 height=100> 
  <rect x=50 y=30 width=100 height=100></rect>

  <svg id="inline" width="50px" viewbox="50 50 100 100">
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=80 y=80></rect>
  </svg>
</svg>
  

<svg viewbox="0 0 300 300" width=100 height=100> 
  <rect x=50 y=30 width=100 height=100></rect>
  <svg id="in-css" viewbox="50 50 100 100">
    <rect width=50 height=50 x=80 y=80></rect>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

## Problem

Setting the width or height attribute of the inner svg works if I do it inline, but I can't set it if I try targeting that element with css. Does anybody know why? I'm *using chrome* for reference if that helps :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I can't seem to apply any css styles to the inner svg.

Comment: It should be `width: 50px` instead of `width=50px`, but I still don't seem to be able to get the width to apply correctly. It applies to the element, but doesn't seem to do anything. Specificity certainly isn't an issue either. You can style that element directly with attributes like `fill` though, which is why it surprises me that `width` has no effect.

Comment: Yep sorry, that was a typo, I should fix that. (I just coppied it out of the inner tag). I posted this because it surprised me as well :P

Comment: I should add that firefox displays the same behaviour. So It shouldn't be a chrome bug I don't think.

Comment: Because that's how SVG 1.1 says it should work. I.e. its by design. SVG 2 proposes changing things but the specification is still being implemented by all browsers. Looks like none have done the bit you want.

Comment: Well, to get around this, I tried using symbols as well, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with symbols either. Is there any way to get around this without javascript?

Comment: I'm also having an issue with this in March of 2020 - here's [my codepen with a similar example](https://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/qBdxzPW). I was about to post a question but saw this one, which didn't get any traction. Is there still no answer to this?